# How would you recommend integrating craft with Algolia

Tags: search

Has anyone had experience integrating craft with algolia: https://www.algolia.com for realtime search of craft entries.

It seems like there are a few potential approaches with their Php and Js libraries. Does anyone recommend a particular approach or best practice for integrating a service like this with Craft.

Comment: Is this purely for the front-end?  i.e. not replace the default search capabilities of the CP.

Comment: Yup just front-end

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disclaimer : I'm the dev of the SearchPlus plugin

The [SearchPlus](http://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/searchplus) plugin by [SquareBit](http://squarebit.co.uk) (currently in private beta) integrates directly with Algolia and handles all the index population and updates.

There's also a few helpers for integrating on the front-end.

All told - you should be able to just drop the plugin onto the site, configure your indexes and start a population action, drop a bit of js on the front-end and you're done.

[Drop me a line](http://squarebit.co.uk/contact) and I'll get you on the beta.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a pretty straight forward integration with a Craft [plugin](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/introduction), then.

They've already got a PHP client up on [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/algolia/algoliasearch-client-php) and what looks to be pretty [extensive documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/php#setup) how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open-source Craft 2.x plugin for Algolia:
https://github.com/joshuabaker/craft-algolia

I haven't used it, but it would be a good place to start.